# jQuery parents() and parent().parent() only see one level up?

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

I am having some issues with getting the list of parents of an element with jQuery.

Perhaps I am missing something, but I have a link inside several nested divs, and am trying to get a list of siblings of the parent's parent.

I only seem to be able to go one level up from the link though, so I can't

The HTML is as follows:

```
<div class="alertcontainer">
   <div id="alertnode_1" class="alertnode">
      <div class="alertnodeheader">Escalate to Level 1</div>
      <div class="alertnodebody">
         <div class="bold">Alert these people:</div><br/>
         <div class="alertnodebodycontactlist">
            <div class="alertnodebodycontact">187   
               <a id="d0.9659762698410487" 
                  onclick="RemoveNode(this, 187)" 
                  href="#">Remove Me...</a>
            </div>
            <div class="alertnodebodycontact">185   
               <a id="d0.6609632486132389" 
                  onclick="RemoveNode(this, 185)" 
                  href="#">Remove Me...</a>
            </div>
            <div class="alertnodebodycontact">184   
               <a id="d0.13180038199138278" 
                  onclick="RemoveNode(this, 184)" 
                  href="#">Remove Me...</a>
            </div>
            <div class="alertnodebodycontact">186   
               <a id="d0.6364304467227213" 
                  onclick="RemoveNode(this, 186)" 
                  href="#">Remove Me...</a>
            </div>
            <select class="esccontactlist" id="esc_contact_list_1">
               <option>Also alert...</option>
            </select>
         </div>
         <br/>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

JS/jQuery as follows:

```
function RemoveNode(e, id)
{
   // Remove the contact
   $(e).parents().filter('.alertnodebodycontact').remove();

   // Add it back into the list.
   for ( var i = 0; i < ContactList.length; i++) 
   {
      if ( id == ContactList[i]["ContactID"] )
      {
         $('#esc_contact_list_1')
            .append("<option value='"
               +ContactList[i]["ContactID"]
               +"'>&nbsp;&nbsp;"
               +ContactList[i]["ContactName"]
               +" ("
               +ContactList[i]["PrimaryEmail"]
               +")</option>");
      }

      // Here, I want to count the number of '.alertnodebodycontact' divs.
      // However, $(e).parents() only returns a single item, which is the 
      // '.alertnodebodycontact'  that the link is in.  
      //  Likewise, $(e).parent().parent() returns nothing.

      // Anyone have any idea why the outer divs aren't being returned?

   }
}
```

Comment: Instead of putting inline javascript in the anchor elements, you could bind to the click event of each anchor in $(document).ready() and pass in itself as an argument, along with it's parent text

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nevermind... I am trying to access it after removing it.  Just need to re-order my tasks.

Comment: Thanks for this - made me realize I was doing the same thing. An event called with trigger() wasn't bubbling up and it took this for me realize it was because I was firing the event from the element after it was removed from the DOM :)

Comment: Good to know I'm not the only one... =o)